# Event listener not active after table refresh

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, dom-events

I have an event listener on a table to indicate the current ID of a row when clicked.
It works perfectly when the row is clicked on initially, but when ajax is triggered after dropdown change,  and table refreshed, the event listener is not working any more. Why?

initial file:

```
<?php   
 //load_data_select.php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "re", "", "test");  
 function fill_brand($connect)  
 {  
      $output = '';  
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM brand";  
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {  
           $output .= '<option value="'.$row["brand_id"].'">'.$row["brand_name"].'</option>';  
      }  
      return $output;  
 }  
 function fill_product($connect)  
 {  
      $output = '<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
<table id="mytable" name="table_1">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>PRODUCT</th>
    <th>BRAND ID</th>
  </tr>';  
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM product";  
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {  
           $output .= '<div class="col-md-3">';  
           $output .= '<tr>
    <td  id="'.$row["product_id"].'">'.$row["product_id"].'</td>
     <td  id="'.$row["product_id"].'">'.$row["product_name"].'</td>
      <td  id="'.$row["product_id"].'">'.$row["brand_id"].'</td>
   </tr>';  

      }  
      $output .= '</table>';
      return $output;  
 }  
 ?>  
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <title>ok</title>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br /><br />  
           <div class="container">  
                <h3>  
                     <select name="brand" id="brand">  
                          <option value="">Show All Product</option>  
                          <?php echo fill_brand($connect); ?>  
                     </select>  
                     <br /><br />  
                     <div class="row" id="show_product">  
                          <?php echo fill_product($connect);?>  
                     </div>  
                </h3>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>  
 <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  

     var table = document.querySelector('#mytable');

// listen for a click
table.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
    var serviceID = ev.target.id;
    alert(serviceID);
})


      $('#brand').change(function(){  
           var brand_id = $(this).val();  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"load_data.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{brand_id:brand_id},  
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#show_product').html(data);  
                }  
           });  
      });  
 });  
 </script>
```

and then the second file (load_data.php) to refresh the table:

```
 <?php  
 //load_data.php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "re", "", "test");  
 $output = '';  
 if(isset($_POST["brand_id"]))  
 {  
      if($_POST["brand_id"] != '')  
      {  
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE brand_id = '".$_POST["brand_id"]."'";  
      }  
      else  
      {  
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM product";  
      }  
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
      $output .= ' <style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>



<table id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>PRODUCT</th>
    <th>BRAND ID</th>
  </tr>';
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {  
           $output .= ' <tr>
    <td id="'.$row["product_id"].'">'.$row["product_id"].'</td>
     <td id="'.$row["product_id"].'">'.$row["product_name"].'</td>
      <td id="'.$row["product_id"].'">'.$row["brand_id"].'</td>
   </tr>'; }  

       $output .= '</table>';
      echo $output;  
 }  
 ?>
```

Comment: You're not refreshing a table, you're creating a new one. The event listener gets deleted along with the old table, so you'll need to add it back on each refresh.

Comment: When Ajax finishes , upon success ?